# Preventing Terminal from creating duplicate Profile tabs after exiting current Profile

Tags: terminal, configuration-profiles

I'm running MacOS 11.7.7

I have created a Terminal profile that starts a shell session. I have exported the profile to be saved in a file called MyProfile.terminal.

I can open the session any time I want by selecting MyProfile.terminal, and when I exit the session, it properly deletes the terminal screen, because I created the profile to close the window and never ask about that, when the session terminates.

However, there is an intermittent problem.

Sometimes, after running and then exiting from MyProfile.terminal, the next time I invoke it, the Terminal screen shows two tabs for that same profile. One is for the newly started session, and one is for the previous session that had been closed. This doesn't happen all the time. It occurs maybe around 50 percent of the time. For the other 50 percent of the time, I indeed only get one Profile tab when I start MyProfile.terminal.

I don't want any of these duplicate tabs. Every time I exit from MyProfile.terminal and then restart it later, I want to see one and only one tab, only for the newly started session.

How can I ensure that Terminal never shows me that extra Profile tab?

Thank you very much in advance.